# Accessing Classes in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i am created one new project in that i added class library, like business layer, datalayer, but when i am accessing the business class in datalayer, class object is created but, when i am accessing the fileds of that class like example :

```
EmpBL objEmb= new EmpBL();
```

objEmb is not coming in intellesence, even i am not accessing the fileds of business class can you help me out please. 
 [image]

Comment: Did you add reference to `ComacCRM.Business` in `CosmacCRM.Web` or which ever project you are trying to access EmpBL from?

Comment: [Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) to the class library in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on your data layer project, select Add Reference and select Project tab - then add reference to your .Business project.

However, you can now have circular references, i.e. you can't reference each other. And normally, Business Objects project references Data Access project, not the other way around. Although any architecture is possible, and sometimes BOL project is just storage classes, and they don't know anything about DAL - a third project brings them together. Not sure about your exact architecture.